# "Hat erfolgt"? Echt?

Tags: verb, conjugation, sein-or-haben

[Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/erfolgen) meint, das Hilfsverb für *erfolgen* sei *haben*. Wenn man den Link öffnet, findet man aber, dass es mit *sein* das Partizip bildet.

Ich erkenne ein paar Verben, die mit beiden Hilfsverben konjugiert werden können. Zum Beispiel ist *fahren* nicht transitiv, so ist es mit *sein* zu konjugieren. Steht aber da ein Akkusativobjekt, dann hingegen mit *haben.*

> - Gestern bin ich zum Bahnhof gefahren.
> - Gestern habe ich meinen Großvater zum Bahnhof gefahren.

Anscheinend nimmt *erfolgen* aber kein Akkusativobjekt an, weswegen ich die Frage stelle.

Comment: Mit "schwimmen" und anderen derartigen Verben ist es Interpretationssache... "Ich bin eine 5 km Strecke geschwommen" ist genauso richtig und zumindest meiner Ansicht nach idiomatischer.

Comment: Someone should correct this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ziemlich sicher liegt Wiki hier falsch. Du kannst "erfolgen" vergleichen mit den nahezu gleichbedeutenden Verben "passieren" und "geschehen", die auch mit dem Hilfsverb "sein" ihr Perfekt bilden.

Ich habe noch nie gehört, dass etwas erfolgt *habe*.

Comment: Nota bene: [Duden only mentions "ist"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erfolgen).

Answer (score 2):

Etwas *ist* erfolgt. "Erfolgen" ist auch intransitiv.

Hier ein paar Synonyme, die ihr Perfekt auch mit "sein" bilden (als Merkhilfe):

- ist geschehen
- ist passiert
- ist eingetreten

Mit Wiktionary sollte man genauso umgehen wie mit Wikipedia. In drei der fünf Quellen findet man "ist erfolgt" bzw. "erfolgt sind". [Damals](https://www.google.at/search?q=ervoelget&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3afr%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=J3GGU8rWF6Oh8wePp4CwDw#channel=fflb&q=ist+ervolget&rls=org.mozilla%3afr%3aofficial) wie auch [heute](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erfolgen).

Comment: Mit transitiv oder nicht hat das nichts zu tun. Schlafen ist auch intransitiv und trotzdem mit "haben". Wäre schön, wenn du das aus der Antwort nehmen könntest.

Comment: Das behaupte ich auch nicht, es ist lediglich als zusätzliche Information gedacht.

Comment: Wiktionary sollte man aber auch im guten Glauben begegnen. Solange der beitragende Nutzer kein unerfahrener Fremdsprachler war, ist anzunehmen, dort werde auch so gesprochen. Das war die Frage. Ob anderswo anders gesprochen wird ist meines erachtens sekundär. Ob das an transitiv liegt oder nicht, zumindest ist hiesige Frage dazu in den related links [zum Thema](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17976/bilden-transitive-verben-das-perfekt-immer-mit-haben) und das Beispiel oben ist ein gutes. Man sagt übrigens "ich *bin* eingeschlafen", nicht *habe*.

Answer (score 2):

Laut *Duden – Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache* sowie *Duden – Deutsches Universalwörterbuch* wird das Perfekt des Verbs „erfolgen“ mit dem Hilfsverb „ist“ gebildet.
Die grammatischen Angaben stehen in spitzen Klammern:

> **er|fọl|gen** 〈sw. V.; ist〉 [mhd. ervolgen = erreichen; refl. = sich zutragen]: *als Folge von etw. geschehen, eintreten, vor sich gehen*:
>
> (…)
>
> es ist noch keine Antwort erfolgt *(es ist noch nicht geantwortet worden)*
>
> (…)