# Bilden transitive Verben das Perfekt immer mit "haben"?

Tags: verb, perfect-tense

Beim [Duden-Verlag](https://web.archive.org/web/20170903221210/http://www.duden.de:80/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/perfektbildung-mit--em-haben--em--oder--em-sein--em-), bei [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Valenz/Trans-Intrans.html), auf [Deutsche Grammatik 2.0](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/verbformen/die-konjugation-perfekt/bildung-perfekt-haben-sein-tranistiv-intransitive-verbvarianten/), wahrscheinlich auch noch in anderen Quellen und neulich sogar [hier am Rande einer anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17910/why-do-some-dictionaries-have-rad-fahren-and-others-radfahren-is-rad-a-separabl/17916#comment40948_17916) findet man die Aussage, daß transitive Verben das Perfekt immer mit *haben* bilden und folglich Verben, die das Perfekt mit *sein* bilden, nicht transitiv sein können.

Andererseits findet man verschiedene Definitionen von Transitivität:

- Verben mit direktem Akkusativobjekt, z.b. auf [grammatiken.de](https://www.grammatiken.de/grammatik-glossar/transitives.html)
- Verben mit direktem Akkusativobjekt und attribuierbarem Partizip II ([grammis 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20181003011601/http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de:80/call/public/termwb.ansicht?v_app=g))
- Verben mit zwei obligatorischen Argumenten ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitivit%C3%A4t_(Grammatik)#Festlegung_der_Transitivit.C3.A4t_eines_Verbs))

die keinen Bezug auf die Perfektbildung nehmen und auch keine Aussage dazu treffen.

Wenn ich mir nun folgende Sätze anschaue:

> Ich bin **den Jakobsweg** gewandert.
>     Er ist **die schnellste Runde** gelaufen.
>     Sie ist schon **viele Bahnen** geschwommen. (zu sehen auf der oben verlinkten Duden-Seite!)
>     Er ist **Weltrekord** gelaufen.
>     Sie ist **Rad** gefahren.

so sehe ich da lauter Perfekt-Sätze mit "sein" und direkten Akkusativobjekten. Zumindest bei "freundlicher" Betrachtung erfüllen sie auch die zweite Transitivitäts-Definition von grammis 2.0. Der Wikipedia-Artikel ist mir für eine aktive Anwendung offen gestanden "zu hoch".

**Enthalten meine Beispielsätze transitive Verben? Wenn ja: Warum verlangen die eingangs zitierten Quellen eine Perfektbildung mit *haben*? Wenn nein: Welches Kriterium für Transitivität wird verletzt?**

Comment: Ich habe noch ein heißes Beispiel: **Ich bin *ihn* losgeworden.**

Comment: @BarthZalewski Danke!!! Besonders gefällt mir, daß das Verb [loswerden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/loswerden) _immer_ ein Akkusativobjekt braucht, im Gegensatz zu den Bewegungsverben, die (mit entsprechend verschobener Bedeutung) auch gut ohne auskommen.

Comment: In diesem Zusammenhang kann es auch vorteilhaft sein, die Entstehungsgeschichte des Perfekts zu betrachten. Im Ahd. wurde der Satz *Der Mann hat einen Hund gefunden(en)* mit nachgestelltem Adjektiv gebildet - *haben* im Sinne von *besitzen* (früher auch: *Der Mann hat einen Hund schwarz(en)*). Das wurde als neue Zeitform reanalysiert; heute also *Der Mann hat einen Hund gefunden*. Vergleicht man das mit *Der Hund ist gekommen*, lässt sich die Frage darauf zurückführen, wie das Partizip verstanden wurde: Ist der Hund *gefunden*, dann fand der Mann. Ist der Hund *gekommen*, dann kam der Hund.

Answer (score 4):

(Manchmal ist es wirklich hilfreich, die eigenen Google-Trouvaillen genau zu lesen, und auch noch ein paar Links weiter zu schauen...)

Ich beziehe mich auf die zweite Definition von Transitivität in meiner Frage, also die von [grammis 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20181003011601/http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de:80/call/public/termwb.ansicht?v_app=g). Nach dieser Definition enthält keines der genannten Beispiele ein transitives Verb.

Ich habe die Definition in meiner Frage ungenau wiedergegeben. Bei grammis 2.0 ist von einem Akkusativ*komplement* die Rede. Nach dem dort vertretenen Konzept werden [drei syntaktische Funktionen](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/?v_typ=d&v_id=1657) in einem Satz unterschieden: der *Verbalkomplex*, die *Komplemente*, die den Verbalkomplex zu einem Satz *ergänzen*, und die *Supplemente*, die den Satz *erweitern*.

Es wird zwar eingeräumt, daß es "notorisch schwierig" sei, Komplemente und Supplemente voneinander abzugrenzen, jedoch hilft dabei ein [dreistufiger Test](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/?v_typ=d&v_id=1527). Alle fünf Beispiele aus meiner Frage bestehen die erste Stufe, den [Reduktionstest](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/?v_typ=d&v_id=1528) - ohne die markierten Satzglieder sind die Sätze immer noch grammatisch und ändern auch nicht wesentlich ihre Bedeutung. Jedoch bestehen sie nicht den [Folgerungstest](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/?v_typ=d&v_id=1529). Während man "ich esse" immer versteht als "ich esse *etwas*", gibt es für die Beispiele keine entsprechenden neutralen, allgemeinen Platzhalter. (Bei "ich wandere" könnte man noch ein paar Hühneraugen zudrücken und argumentieren, dass man immer irgendeinen Weg wandert, aber dann geht der dritte Test eindeutig schief.) Die aufgeführten Verben regieren somit kein Akkusativ*komplement*, vielmehr handelt es sich bei den im Akkusativ stehenden Satzgliedern um Supplemente.

Ich halte diese Unterscheidung in Komplemente und Supplemente für klarer als die Trennung nach Adverbialen und Objekten, die in den Antworten von Grantwalzer und Barth Zalewski angeboten wurde (die aber im Kern in die gleiche Richtung geht), nicht zuletzt wegen des angebotenen Testverfahrens.

Meine eigenen Beispiele können also nicht als Gegenbeispiele für das Problem im Titel der Frage dienen, jedoch haben Veredomon und Barth Zalewski weitere interessante Kandidaten beigetragen:

> 1. Wir sind die Papiere durchgegangen.
> 2. Wir sind den Vertrag eingegangen.
> 3. Ich bin ihn losgeworden.

In allen drei Fällen spricht schon der Reduktionstest für Komplemente. Bei 2.) habe ich auch keine Zweifel am "attribuierbaren Partizip" (*der eingegangene Vertrag*), bei 1.) und 3.) hingegen schon ein wenig: *die durchgegangenen Papiere* und *der losgewordene Schrott* klingen für mich ziemlich unnormal, aber da kann man sicher auch streiten. Eine eigene Frage wäre es wohl wert, warum bei grammis 2.0 dieses zweite Kriterium überhaupt gefordert wird. Interessanterweise führt [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Tempora/HabenSein.html?lang=de) alle 3 Verben als Beispiele für Ausnahmen von der Regel, das Perfekt von transitiven Verben mit "haben" zu bilden. Warum sie die Existenz solcher Ausnahmen bei der [Vorstellung der Transitivität](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Valenz/Trans-Intrans.html) nicht mal andeuten, bleibt ihr Geheimnis.

Die Antwort auf die Frage im Titel hat also Radio Jerewan: "Im Prinzip ja. Aber es gibt ein paar Ausnahmen."

Comment: Danke. Als evtl. interessanten Zusatz, ich habe "eingehen" im historischen Korpus von COSMAS II gesucht. Der Sinn "Vertrag eingehen" findet sich schon im 19. Jahrhundert, das ist also keine neuere Entwicklung.

Answer (score 3):

In Deutsche Morphologie (Hentschel, Vogel) werden zwei transitive Verben erwähnt:

> Wir sind *die Papiere* durchgegangen.
>   Wir sind *den Vertrag* eingegangen.

An diesem Beispiel kann man sogar eine deutliche Bedeutungsveränderung zwischen transitivem und intransitivem Gebrauch beobachten:

> Das Pferd ist durchgegangen.
>   Der Kaktus ist eingegangen, der Brief ist eingegangen.
>   Die andere Firma hat den Vertrag vorgelegt, #wir sind eingegangen.

Die Verben haben ganz klar ein Akkusativobjekt. Insofern ist die Behauptung, alle mit *sein* ins Perfekt gesetzte Verben seien intransitiv, falsch.

Comment: +1 Du gehst zwar nur auf den Titel meiner Frage ein und nicht auf den Fließtext, dafür aber sehr überzeugend.

Answer (score 3):

Das sind meist keine Objekte, sondern ausgeschriebene Adverbien, so wie das hier:

> Ich bin *diesen Monat* viel gelaufen.

Die Regel, dass alle transitiven Verben das Perfekt mit `haben` bilden ist weitestgehend korrekt und ist ein Teil der wunderschönen Logik der deutschen Sprache.

Allerdings zeigt das Beispiel von @Veredomon und das Kommentar von vorhin von meiner Wenigkeit ein anderes Verhalten.

> Wir sind die Papiere durchgegangen. --> Wir **sind** durch die Papiere durch.
>
> Ich bin ihn losgeworden. --> Ich **bin** ihn los.

Es scheint also, dass die Benutzung von **sein** in diesem Kontext dadurch erklärt wird, dass die Beschreibung des Endzustandes das Verb **sein** erfordert. Vergleiche:

> Ich bin weggegangen. --> Ich bin weg.

Dagegen mit **haben**:

> Du hast gekocht. --> Du hast etwas Gekochtes.

Man sollte dies nicht allzu strikt sehen, aber als Denkanstoß.

Man beachte, dass alle **Reflexivverben** *auch* transitive Verben sind (das Subjekt ist zugleich das Objekt), wodurch auch alle reflexiven Verben ihr Perfekt mit `haben` bilden.

> Ich habe mich an dich gewendet.

Wenn man also etwas mit "sich selbst" machen kann, kann man es auch mit anderen Personen / Sachen machen.

> sich an etwas erinnern **vs** jemanden an etwas erinnern

Diese Logik ist spezifisch für Deutsch, andere Sprachen sind da nicht so nachvollziehbar:

> *portugiesisch*: **esquecer-se** - vergessen
>
> *polnisch*: **śmiać się** - lachen

Comment: Man beachte, daß `durchgehen` und `loswerden` im Sinne der zweiten von mir verlinkten Definition nicht transitiv sind, weil sie keine attribuierbaren Partizipien bilden ("<s>die durchgegangenen Papiere</s>"). Auch sehe ich einen wesentlichen Unterschied zwischen "diesen Monat viel laufen" (Adverb) und "eine weite Strecke laufen" (Objekt). Vor allem aber kann ich hier keine Antwort auf die konkret von mir gestellten Fragen herauslesen.

Comment: Tolle Antwort! @Matthias Dass es kein echtes Objekt ist, sieht man an folgendem Beispiel: eine Menge laufen.

Comment: "Wunderschöne Logik der deutschen Sprache" - ich suche immer noch nach Anzeichen, daß Du das ironisch gemeint haben könntest. Ansonsten zwar nur ein sehr knappes Eingehen auf meine Frage, dafür aber viel Lesenswertes zum Umfeld. Danke und +1.

Comment: @Grantwalzer Ok, da habe ich Dir mit dem Adjektiv "weite" eine Vorlage gegeben. Dein Einwand käme gegen "eine gefährliche Strecke laufen" aber schon nicht mehr zum Tragen. Macht aber nichts, ich hab die Idee inzwischen gerafft, siehe meine eigene Antwort.

Answer (score 2):

Bei den Beispielsätzen handelt es sich um Verben der Bewegung, die grundsätzlich nur ein Argument benötigen (das Subjekt), also intransitiv sind.

Die zusätzlichen **Akkusativobjekte** sehen eher wie Adverbialbestimmungen aus - der Unterschied zu einem Argument ist unscharf: Ein Argument kann frei(er) gewählt werden, 
während solche Akkusativ- objekte aus dem Wortfeld des Verbs stammen müssen. ZB ist die transitive Verwendung von "essen" vielseitiger als die vermeintlich transitive Verwendung von "fahren":

> Sie hat ein Rad gegessen. Sie hat einen Apfel gegessen.
>   Sie ist (ein) Rad gefahren. <strike>Sie ist einen Apfel gefahren.</strike>

Es finden sich sicherlich Kombinationen mit "echten" transitiven Verben, die gleichsam falsch erscheinen, wie etwa "Den Jakobsweg hören", aber auch hier ist "hören" (zumindest interpretationstechnisch) flexibler als "wandern":

> Den Jakobsweg hören. (?) [Dieses Lied](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SOb_xlnpPQ) hören.
>   Den Jakobsweg wandern. <strike>[Dieses Lied](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FWXcuRdxOI) wandern.</strike>

Comment: Das überzeugt mich (noch) nicht. "Essen" _benötigt_ ein zweites Argument ebensowenig wie "wandern". Hinsichtlich des Einsatzes ist m.E. jedes Verb auf sein "Wortfeld" beschränkt, nur ist dieses mal größer, mal kleiner, und im Fall von "essen" sehr groß (alles Materielle), weshalb es in Deinem Beispiel nach einem signifikanten Unterschied aussieht. Ich kann eine Kurve fahren, eine E-Mail schreiben und einen Apfel essen, aber jedes dieser 3 Objekte ergibt mit den jeweils anderen Verben _gleichermaßen_ unsinnige Phrasen.

Comment: @Matthias Das versuche ich im zweiten und dritten Absatz zwar einzuräumen, aber diese drei Beispiele (oder auch nur die zwei transitiven Varianten von "schreiben" und "essen") sind tatsächlich gänzlich unflexibel. Ehrlich gesagt überzeugt mich die Antwort in ihrer jetzigen Form selbst auch nicht - sie repräsentiert auch nicht wirklich meine Meinung, sondern war eher ein Versuch mit der im Internet auffindbaren Information dazu den infrage stehenden Preskriptivismus aufrechtzuerhalten (ist so ein Hobby von mir), um nicht immer alles mit "Ausnahme" betiteln zu müssen.

Comment: Aber warum nicht? Vielleicht konnte man früher die Bewegungsverben nicht mit Akkusativobjekten versehen, während (noch früher) Verben wie "essen" oder "schreiben" immer ein Argument haben mussten (wie im Lateinischen?), also die einen echt intransitiv und die anderen echt transitiv waren, und deshalb die Hilfsverben für die neuen Varianten "Er schreibt" und "Ich fahre eine Kurve" immer noch die alten sind. Vielleicht findet sich im Grimm was.

Comment: Danke trotzdem! Könntest Du noch Quellen angeben, wo im Internet Du diese Informationen aufgefunden hast? Der zeitliche Aspekt ist mir auch schon in den Sinn gekommen. Vielleicht waren meine Gegenbeispiele früher noch nicht üblich?