# Perfect Auxiliary of Transitive Verbs

Tags: standard-german, perfect-tense

Can transitive verbs only taken “haben” as an auxiliary (ie, as opposed to “sein”)? I am not aware of a counter-example to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bilden transitive Verben das Perfekt immer mit "haben"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17976/bilden-transitive-verben-das-perfekt-immer-mit-haben)

Comment: @DavidVogt _not_ a duplicate. There’s [a community decision to treat questions in different languages not as duplicates](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/807/9325). Linking to the other is recommended, though.

Comment: @DavidVogt how about writing an answer _in the asker‘s preferred language_? Not all users are fluent enough to understand the answer in German (or speak English well enough in the reverse case).

Comment: @Aaron Please do not usage the tag [standard-german](https://german.stackexchange.com/tags/standard-german/info) for questions such as this one. Quoting from the linked page: *Only use this tag for questions about standard German as such, e.g., how it is defined, when it is used, or how it relates to other variants of German.

Do not use it to indicate that you want to know about a particular grammatical feature, rule of orthography, or word in Standard German. This is not necessary, as standard German is assumed as the default anyway.*

Answer (score 3):

For the great majority of *sein-Perfekt-Verben*, this is true. There are even verbs which may be used transitively or intransitively, for example *fahren*:

> Er **ist** in die Waschanlage gefahren.
>
> Er **hat den Wagen** in die Waschanlage gefahren.

However, German cannot exist without exceptions, as noted in the German-language answer given in the comments:

> Der Wagen **ist den Dreck** dort losgeworden.
>
> Er **ist die Akte** durchgegangen.
>
> Sie **sind einen Pakt mit dem Teufel** eingegangen.

Comment: Would you mind providing a quick definition of "ist-Perfekt-Verben"? Thanks for the answer though! Very helpful.

Comment: Also, I know the auxiliaries can vary between regions so are the exceptions Hochdeutsch?

Comment: Verbs that build their Perfekt with *ist/sein*. Nothing special. If you wanted to discuss those in detail, another question would be better.

Comment: Yes, especially Southern German has a lot more verbs that build their Perfekt with *sein*.